# Firefox plugin to block scripts of only specified websites

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, plugins, script, blocking

I'm looking for a Firefox plugin that blocks JavaScript from specified URLs.

Example:

- I add: "google-analytics.com"
- It then blocks all scripts coming from Google Analytics.

Essentially a blacklist of sites that I don't want to allow JavaScript from.

**Note:** I know of NoScript which blocks all scripts from all websites. But I don't want that.

Comment: By the way, you're asking for an "extension", which interacts with Firefox's or one of its siblings' or a XULRunner application's internals to "extend" its functionality, and named such to reduce confusion with plugins. A web "plugin" is a de-facto cross-browser technology whereby a page "plugs in" a window controlled by a separate binary, like Flash or Java or a media player.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/722) is a common solution. It uses whitelisting by default -- but as Kelbizzle notes, supports blacklisting -- and also helps with vulnerabilities related to XSS.
- [YesScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/4922) is a blacklist-only alternative to the tangled code of NoScript.
- [AdBlock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/1865)'s [filter options](https://adblockplus.org/en/filters#options) can also solve this: `google-analytics.com$script`. This is my choice because it makes managing and copying filter rules extremely easy.
- [RequestPolicy](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/9727) allows you to block third-party resources, including script. This is a whitelist with a a few useful temporary or permanent "allow all" options, and it doesn't differentiate between type of resource like ABP does.
- [Karma Blocker](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/5230) is a resource blocker that is apparently as powerful as ABP, but it requires more thought to configure than the other options.

Comment: +1 for AdBlock Plus. You can block pretty much anything using filters.

Comment: Anothing awesome lightweight blocker is [uBlock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/) - it is by far the most resource friendly blocker, with a support for blocking requests based on AdBlock Plus filters + third party assests blocking (such as scripts and frames), highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

No script is what you want. It has a [Blacklist](http://noscript.net/features#blacklist) feature.

Comment: If you don't like no script. This https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4922 may be exactly what you're looking for. It blocks javascript from  only the sites you tell it.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Blocksite](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/blocksite/).  It allows the use of wildcards so you can add something like "http*google-analytics.com*".